# Scraping Instagram followers page using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a question related to scraping the instagram followers page. I have a code but it displays only 9 followers. Kindly help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def login(driver):
    username = "xxxx@yahoo.com"  # <username here>
    password = "xxxx"  # <password here>

    # Load page
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

    # Login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/button").click()

    # Wait for the login page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "See All")))


def scrape_followers(driver, account):
    # Load account page
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/{0}/".format(account))

    # Click the 'Follower(s)' link
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("follower").click()

    # Wait for the followers modal to load
    xpath = "//div[@style='position: relative; z-index: 1;']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

    # You'll need to figure out some scrolling magic here. Something that can
    # scroll to the bottom of the followers modal, and know when its reached
    # the bottom. This is pretty impractical for people with a lot of followers

    # Finally, scrape the followers
    xpath = "//div[@style='position: relative; z-index: 1;']//ul/li/div/div/div/div/a"
    followers_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

    return [e.text for e in followers_elems]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    try:
        login(driver)
        followers = scrape_followers(driver, "instagram")
        print(followers)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

This code was taken from another page. I dont understand how to scroll down the followers page.

Comment: here is what i would google: selenium scroll

Answer (score 3):

You have to add one for loop so that you can scroll down the page for the followers. This for loop can be like this:

```
#Find the followers page
dialog = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]')
#find number of followers
allfoll=int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[2]/a/span").text) 
#scroll down the page
for i in range(int(allfoll/2)):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", dialog)
    time.sleep(random.randint(500,1000)/1000)
    print("Extract friends %",round((i/(allfoll/2)*100),2),"from","%100")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily scroll down using javascript by increasing the scrollTop. You run this scroll until the amount of users in the list no longer changes.

The difference in the amount of users can be checked using the following function

```
count = 0

def check_difference_in_count(driver):
    global count

    new_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@role='dialog']//li"))

    if count != new_count:
        count = new_count
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And the following script scrolls down the user container until it has reached the bottom

```
while 1:
    # scroll down
    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div[role=dialog] ul').parentNode.scrollTop=1e100")

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(check_difference_in_count)
    except:
        break
```